# expand $f(x,y)= x^y$ in $(x-1)$ and $(y-1)$

Tags: taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Useing Taylor expansion and partial derivatives I got to this point
$$\begin{align}f(x,y) &= x^y\\
       &= f(1,1)\\
       &=f(1+(x-1),1+(y-1))\end{align}$$
how do I proceed further.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions; they'll be much more readable.

Comment: Do you know Taylor's theorem in two variables?  What does it say?

Answer (score 2):

You can also solve this without Taylor.

Notice that, setting $u:=x-1,v:=y-1$,

$$x^y=x(1+u)^{v}$$

and using the Generalized Binomial formula,

$$x^y=
\\(1+u)\left(1+vu+\frac{v(v-1)}{2!}u^2+\frac{v(v-1)(v-2)}{3!}u^3+\cdots\right).$$

Then you have to expand the falling factorials

$$v(v-1)(v-2)=v^3-3v^2+2v$$ and the like.

The coefficients of these polynomials are the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), with alternating signs. To deal with the factor $(1+u)$, you need to add the coefficients in successive pairs.

Comment: the question asks me to solve using Taylor's expansion ...

Comment: @PranshuGupta: yes, you said it. This can be used to check the answer.